# Submit React form without button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to handle a form with select buttons in React. Select buttons are for different product variations of a eCommerce product detail page. Basically, how to have component automatically handleForm whenever user changes size/color to small (or whatever product variations the API has), so by the time I POST it has the variation in the request.

In theory, I could just put a submit button but he/she would have to re-submit each time they change from small to medium.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { productDetailURL, addToCartURL } from '../constants'
import { fetchCart } from "../store/actions/cart";
import { authAxios } from '../utils'


class ProductDetail extends React.Component {

    state = {
        loading: false,
        error: null,
        formData: {},
        data: []
      };

    handleChange = (e) => {
      const { formData } = this.state
      const updatedFormData = {
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
      this.setState({formData: updatedFormData})
    }

    handleFormatData = formData => {
      // convert {colour: 1, size: 2} to [1,2] - they're all variations
      return Object.keys(formData).map(key => {
        return formData[key];
      });
    };


    componentDidMount() {
    const {match: { params }} = this.props
    axios
      .get(productDetailURL(params.productID))
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({ error: err, loading: false });
      });
    }

    handleAddToCart = slug => {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        const { formData } = this.state
        const variations = this.handleFormatData(formData)
        console.log(variations)
        authAxios
          .post(addToCartURL, { slug, variations })
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.setState({ error: err, loading: false });
          });
      };

    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        const { data, error, loading, formData } = this.state;
        const  item  = data
        return (
            <div>
            <div class="container">
            {error && (
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {JSON.stringify(error) }
            </div>
            )}
            {loading && (
            <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
            )}
          <div class="card">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <aside class="col-md-6">
        <article class="gallery-wrap">
        <div class="img-big-wrap">
          <div> <a href="#"><img src="/images/items/12.jpg"></img></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbs-wrap">
          <a href="#" class="item-thumb"> <img src="/images/items/12.jpg"></img></a>
          <a href="#" class="item-thumb"> <img src="/images/items/12-1.jpg"></img></a>
          <a href="#" class="item-thumb"> <img src="/images/items/12-2.jpg"></img></a>
        </div>
        </article> 
            </aside>
            <main class="col-md-6 border-left">
        <article class="content-body">

        <h2 class="title">{item.title}</h2>

<div class="rating-wrap my-3">
    <ul class="rating-stars">
        <li  class="stars-active">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <small class="label-rating text-muted">132 reviews</small>
    <small class="label-rating text-success"> <i class="fa fa-clipboard-check"></i> 154 orders </small>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
    <var class="price h4">${item.price}</var>
</div>

<p>{item.description}</p>

<hr></hr>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md flex-grow-0">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 input-spinner">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" id="button-plus"> + </button>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1"></input>
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" id="button-minus"> − </button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md flex-grow-0">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormatData}>
    {data.variations &&
                data.variations.map(v => {
                  const name = v.name.toLowerCase()
                  return (
                    <Fragment key={v.id}>
                      {/* <div class="card"> */}
                      <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="form-inline d-inline-flex ml-luto">
                      <label as="h3">{v.name}</label>
                      <select className="ml-2 form-control" name={name}  onChange={this.handleChange}>

                        {v.item_variations.map(iv => {
                          return (
                            <option
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            key={iv.id} 
                            value={iv.id}
                            >
                              {iv.value}
                            </option>
                          );
                        })}

                      </select>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      {/* </div> */}
                    </Fragment>
                  );
                })}
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn  btn-primary"> Buy now </a>
            <a onClick={() => this.handleAddToCart(item.slug)} class="btn  btn-outline-primary"> <span class="text">Add to cart</span> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>  </a>
          </article>
              </main>
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      refreshCart: () => dispatch(fetchCart())
    };
  };

  export default withRouter(
    connect(
      null,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(ProductDetail)
  );
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So from your question it seems like you want to store some user preference (product variations) in your local state and want them to be available before you submit the form? And it does look like you have it right! I only see one bug - you have `this.handleChange` on both the `select` tag and the `option`. You only need the onChange handler on the `select` :)

Comment: I did that and moved the add to cart inside form. Worked! Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! I would also say, you don't necessarily have to use a `<form>` tag just to submit the form. You could have the same action on the onClick too. You are storing the form state separately any ways, might as well have the submit handler on its own.